# How to import the source code of existing R package into eclipse (plugin: statET)

Tags: r, eclipse, statet

I am using statET plugin in Eclipse for R. 
I created a new `R package project`, called it `dummy` and compared the structure to that of the source code of an existing R package. Obviously they are different - but I expected that dummy package would have enough hints to be able to identify a place to dump the .r files and start refactoring.
However its not that easy - the dummy package barely contains a .project file and a .settings folder that contains a .prefs file whereas the package source has a completely different structure.

Any guidance on how to achieve an import is highly appreciated!!

Comment: `package.skeleton` contains the minimal amount of file structure for an R package. Why not start by running that code in eclipse? Alternatively. Have a look at the excellent `devtools` package, which is obviously meant to interface with Rstudio.

Comment: While RStudio has done much to tie into `devtools`, a decent # of folks use it with ESS and even the R GUI or Sublime/SublimeREPL. It works quite well standalone. Why someone would want to deal with the horrors of Eclipse is beyond me, though.